# Ubuntu using script to add JAVA_HOME path to bashrc not working

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, path

I am trying to write a script which will add the JAVA_HOME path to bashrc. But I keep getting the wrong output.

Using the script below:

```
echo "export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle" >> ~/.bashrc
echo "export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin" >> ~/.bashrc
```

I get the output below in bashrc

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle
export PATH=/home/ubuntu/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr$
```

The desired output is `export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin` for the path.

This script is not just intended for adding java path, I wan't to add path for hadoop, spark and hbase. I get same output for each of those. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what is the output of the commands if the `>> ~/.bashrc` part is removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening is that $PATH and $JAVA_HOME are being expanded before the line is added to `.bashrc`.

They need to be escaped; e.g.

```
echo "export PATH=\$PATH:\$JAVA_HOME/bin" >> ~/.bashrc
```

or

```
echo 'export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin' >> ~/.bashrc
```

---

However, you want to be really careful with this kind of "brute-force" editing of shell "rc" files.  It can be dangerous.

A better idea would be to either do the changes by hand, or put the settings into the respective wrapper scripts that launch your Java-based applications

Answer (score 0):

echo is just outputting the command text, get rid of the echo, and actually execute the command.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are using double quotes. These evaluate the variables (in this case `$JAVA_HOME`, which isn't set yet). If you use single quotes instead, it will output the literal instead of the evaluated.
e.g.

`echo 'export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin' >> ~/.bashrc`

See [Difference between single and double quotes in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash) for more information.